# How to disable HTTP/2 on IIS of Windows Server 2016

Tags: iis, windows-server-2016

We are running into some issues that seem to be affected by http2 and I want to turn it off temporarily to troubleshoot. I tried the registry keys outlined in this question but that did not help with Windows Server 2016.

[How to disable HTTP/2 on IIS of Windows 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31668151/how-to-disable-http-2-on-iis-of-windows-10)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to disable HTTP/2 on IIS of Windows 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31668151/how-to-disable-http-2-on-iis-of-windows-10)

Comment: See also [How to disable HTTP 1.1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70265394/12597)

Answer (score 20):

1. Start → `regedit`
2. Navigate to the folder/path: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\HTTP\Parameters`
3. Under the *Parameters* folder, right-click the white-space, add 2 new DWORD (32-bit) values:

   - `EnableHttp2Tls`
   - `EnableHttp2Cleartext`
4. Ensure both new values have been set to `0`(disabled) by right-clicking the value and clicking "Modify..."
5. Restart the OS.

Comment: What was the issue you faced? I was facing some very strange bugs related to Authorization headers.

Comment: The solution above works for SSRS web server as well as IIS.  Chrome was unable to display reporting services reports over ssl until http2 was disabled.

Comment: What if I want to enable it for testing. Am I adding these DWORDs with values of 1?

Answer (score 5):

Another solution, if you are only testing, is run Chrome without http2 enabled.  from start run, `chrome --disable-http2`

Also, apparently a fix is coming, we just have to be patient for the rollout.  See [THIS](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=685741) article

Comment: Note that you should first close all chrome windows or everything that uses chrome plugins.