# HTTP2_Protocol Error in Production with https protocol

Tags: c#, reactjs, https, iis-10

While using https with IIS we are intermittently getting `ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR` on Dev tool in Production env.

This works fine with http protocol (QA). We are using IIS 10.

We are using React Framework 16.11.0 version and the fetch method fails.
This happens in all the browsers (edge, chrome etc.) See attachment below.

Sharing below the net log data.

```
{"params":{"**description":"Server reset stream.","net_error":"ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR","stream_id":183},"phase":0,"source":**{"id":2567,"start_time":"1619763469","type":1},"time":"1619779275","type":222},
```

Comment: Team any update on this?

Answer (score 1):

Does the error occur in other browser? Such as Firefox or EDGE. It seems that the error only relates to the client-side not server-side. Alternatively, try to disable HTTP/2 in IIS10.
[How to disable HTTP/2 on IIS of Windows Server 2016](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44660634/how-to-disable-http-2-on-iis-of-windows-server-2016)
or disable `TLS1.2` to see if it works.
https://support.secureauth.com/hc/en-us/articles/360019889231-Enable-Disable-SSL-TLS-versions-via-Registry-Editor
Check this link for more information.
https://forum.seafile.com/t/http-2-breaks-some-functionalities/9474

Comment: This is the same behavior across all the browser. We cannot disable the Http2 protocol.This is in production, In QA env this works without any issue using HTTP.