# How to disable HTTP1.1 and only use HTTP/2 in Windows Server 2016 and IIS 10?

Tags: iis, http2, http-1.1

Traffic to my site is using `HTTP1.1`, and I want to force the server to only use `HTTP/2`.

I'm running Windows Server 2016 and IIS 10.  I've tried adding

- HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\HTTP\Parameters

  - `EnableHttp2Tls: DWORD` = `1`
  - `EnableHttp2ClearText: DWORD` = `1`

but it is still serving `HTTP1.1`.

I'm obviously missing something here, but I'm not exactly sure what.  Is what I'm asking for even possible?

Comment: I don't think HTTP 1.1 is going away yet. There are certain things you won't get in HTTP 2.0 and disabling 1.1 can break quite a few existing web apps. But if you do want to test whether your web apps work in HTTP 2.0 only mode, you can use a URL Rewrite rule to abort all HTTP 1.1 requests.

Comment: The issue I'm running into is that my server has been flagged for having an HTTP Request Smuggling vulnerability.  I read that this is a possible solution to solve the problem by forcing HTTP2

Comment: I think what @LexLi mentioned is [this answer](https://serverfault.com/q/391356). And you may refer to [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/whats-new-in-iis-10/http2-on-iis) and decide if you will insist on using http2.0.

Comment: @js1983 did you resolve it? Because I also need this to prevent vulnerability, I've made a question [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73864296/how-to-disable-http-2-downgrading-to-http-1-1-on-tomcat)

Answer (score 0):

From [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/questions/391356/ignoring-http-1-0-requests-in-iis):

1. Download and install [URL Rewrite](http://www.iis.net/download/URLRewrite).
2. Add the following to your `web.config` file, to the `<system.webServer>` section:

   **web.config**

   ```
   <rewrite>
       <rules>
            <rule name="RequestBlockingRule1" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="*" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{SERVER_PROTOCOL}" pattern="HTTP/1.0" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="AbortRequest" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
   ```

This will refuse all HTTP 1.0 requests with a HTTP 504 error code.

---

After installing URL Rewrite, you can also configure rewrite rules in IIS Manager:

[image]