# How to disable HTTP/1.1? And disable downgrading to HTTP/1.1 on Tomcat?

Tags: java, http, tomcat, http2

I need to leave possibility to execute requests only with **HTTP/2** protocol.

System: Apache Tomcat 8, configured to use the **HTTP/2** protocol.

1. I execute this request with `--http2` and get result:

   [image: Testing with HTTP/2]
2. Next I execute this request with `--http1.1` and get result
   [image]

This picture means that I still can use **HTTP/1.1**, but I want to disable it.

How to prevent executing **HTTP/1.1** request on Tomcat?

Comment: Why do you need to do that?

Comment: I need this for preventing "HTTP Request smuggling" vulnerability, which is present in HTTP/1.1 protocol and earlier versions. In HTTP/2 protocol this vulnerability is solved.

Comment: In the future, [please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). The output of curl for example can easily be posted as text, which is much more accessible.

Comment: [This Serverfault question](https://serverfault.com/questions/1096017/how-to-disable-http-1-0-protocol-in-tomcat) has some limited information on the topic.